# UPDATE _field1 = _feild2 for every row

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to update a Table, and move the data from one row to another? For example, could I use the following syntax?

```
UPDATE _tablename SET _field1 = _field2;
```

Normally `UPDATE` queries require a `WHERE` parameter don't they?

Comment: What you have is fine.

Comment: It doesn't require a `WHERE` - without one, all rows will be updated. But your requirement is unclear - you say in the description _move the data from one row to another_ - but your SQL implies you want to copy from one _column_ to another. Which is it?  To move between _rows_ would require a joining condition between the old and new row.

Comment: No.  And even if a `where` were required, you could use `where 1 = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other syntactic elements are required for an UPDATE query. See [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

all parts enclosed in brackets [] can be omitted keeping syntax intact.